# plot a line in 3D plot in julia

Tags: matplotlib, plot, 3d, julia

I'm trying to plot a line segment between the points [1,1] and [0,0] in the surface Z function x^2 + y^2,
i've already plotted f with:

```
using PyPlot
using Distributions

function f(x)
    return (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)
    #return sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2])
end

n = 100
x = linspace(-1, 1, n)
y = linspace(-1,1,n)

xgrid = repmat(x',n,1)
ygrid = repmat(y,1,n)

z = zeros(n,n)

for i in 1:n
    for j in 1:n
        z[i:i,j:j] = f([x[i],y[j]])
    end
end

plot_wireframe(xgrid,ygrid,z)
```

I know already about R (ggplot2) and C, but i'm new with python and julia librarys like matlibplot

Comment: If you're familiar with `ggplot2`, which is an R implementation of the Grammar of Graphics, you should check out the Julia package Gadfly. It's the native Julia implementation of the Grammar of Graphics.

Comment: I couldn't find an 3D aplication in Gadfly for Júlia

Comment: Is something like `plot3D(linspace(0,1,n), linspace(0,1,n), map(x->f([x,x]), linspace(0,1,n)), color="red")` not what you are looking for?

Comment: more or like that @rickhg12hs, but i'm trying to connect more than 2 points by segment of lines like [0,0,f(0,0)] -> [0,1,f(0,1)] -> [1,1,f(1,1)], like a path that an algorithm have chosen

Comment: Loop over your points?

Comment: No, just plot then connected in this order @rickhg12hs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I've just had to make:

```
using PyPlot
using Distributions

function f(x)
    return (x[1]^2 + x[2]^2)
    #return sin(x[1]) + cos(x[2])
end

n = 100
x = linspace(-1, 1, n)
y = linspace(-1,1,n)

xgrid = repmat(x',n,1)
ygrid = repmat(y,1,n)

z = zeros(n,n)

for i in 1:n
    for j in 1:n
        z[i:i,j:j] = f([x[i],y[j]])
    end
end

plot_wireframe(xgrid,ygrid,z)

## new line
plot([0.0, 1.0, -1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [0.0 , 2.0, 2.0], color="red")
```